# MVC 5 - Information in partial view is null after submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a large form and it's becoming too big so I want to start using partial view to keep it cleaner.

Here is a little part of the form that shows the main contact and a list of alternative contacts. The user can add more contacts (the buttons shows a popup to insert new contact) and the user can change the contact from active to inactive (through the checkbox on the table). Right now this is working but like i said i want to be able to use a partial view for the table.

```
 <div class="box box-primary">
<div class="box-header">
    <h3 class="box-title">Contacts</h3>
</div>
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label>Phone:</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Persons.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "phone" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Persons.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <label>Email:</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Persons.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "email", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Introduza o email..." } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Persons.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label>Address:</label>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Persons.Address, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Introduza a morada...", @rows = 3 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Persons.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            @if (Model.Contacts != null && Model.Contacts.Count > 0)
                {
                <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" aria-describedby="example2_info">
                    <thead>
                        <tr role="row">
                            <th class="sorting_asc" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending">Contact</th>
                            <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Contact Type</th>
                            <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Active</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
                        @{
                                string cssClass = string.Empty;
                                string activo = string.Empty;
                        }

                        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Contacts.Count; i++)
                            {
                                cssClass = i % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd";

                            <tr class="´@cssClass">
                                <td class=" ">@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Contacts[i].Contact)</td>
                                <td class=" ">@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Contacts[i].contacttypes.Name)</td>
                                <td class=" ">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Contacts[i].IsActive, new { @class = "flat-green" })</td>
                            </tr>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Contacts[i].ContactsId)
                            }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="button" value="Add New Contact" class="buttonCreate btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So here is the same HTML using the partial view

```
 <div class="box box-primary">
<div class="box-header">
    <h3 class="box-title">Contacts</h3>
</div>
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label>Phone:</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Persons.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "phone" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Persons.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <label>Email:</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Persons.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "email", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Introduza o email..." } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Persons.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label>Address:</label>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Persons.Address, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Introduza a morada...", @rows = 3 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Persons.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            @Html.Partial("ContactListControl", Model.Contacts)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="button" value="Add New Contact" class="buttonCreate btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the Partial view:

```
@model List<RecruitmentWeb.Models.contacts>
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" aria-describedby="example2_info">
<thead>
    <tr role="row">
        <th class="sorting_asc" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending">Contato</th>
        <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Tipo de Contato</th>
        <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Activo</th>
</thead>
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    @{
        string cssClass = string.Empty;
        string activo = string.Empty;
    }

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        cssClass = i % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd";

        <tr class="´@cssClass">
            <td class=" ">@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].Contact)</td>
            <td class=" ">@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].contacttypes.Name)</td>
            <td class=" ">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model[i].IsActive, new { @class = "flat-green" })</td>
        </tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].ContactsId)
    }
</tbody>
```

**The Problem**

If the user changes a contact from active to inactive or vice-versa, when I submit the form the changes don't go through. In fact, the list is null and contains no information. It works if i don't use partial view.

So what I'm I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passing only a property of your model to the partial so the the hidden inputs you are generating have the name attribute `name="[0].ContactsId"`, `name="[1].ContactsId"` etc. whereas they needs to be `name="Contacts[0].ContactsId"`, `name="Contacts[1].ContactsId"` etc (ditto for the checkboxes).

Change the partial view model to the same as the main view (you haven't indicated what it is), and then pass the model as

```
@Html.Partial("ContactListControl", Model)
```

and adjust the Html helpers to suit. However I would recommend you consider using a custom `EditorTemplate` for `RecruitmentWeb.Models.Contacts` rather than a partial view for this.

Comment: Oh I see. I will try that then. What's the difference between the partial view and an EditorTemplate and how would I implement it?

Comment: got it to work now :D I've also been reading on the EditorTemplates and i think i understand it. But what is the difference between the two?